# Failed to convert parameter value from a Int64 to a Byte[]

Tags: c#, types

I am getting the error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from
>   a Int64 to a Byte[].

Here is what I am doing...

I have a table in my database with the column:

```
sessionid | binary(32) | null
```

When I assign to it, I do this:

```
user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
user.SessionId = user.LastActivityDate.ToBinary();
```

SessionId is an inherited property from an interface:

```
long? SessionId { get; set; }
```

And here it is being accessed in my User class:

```
[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false), CustomProviderData("SessionId;string")]
public long? SessionId { get { return base["SessionId"] as long?; } set { base["SessionId"] = value; } }
```

In my custom profile provider, the following command assigns the value:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("sessionid", SqlDbType.Binary, 32).Value = settingsPropertyValue.PropertyValue;
```

When the "sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()" command executes an update stored 
procedure is executed with the parameter:

```
@sessionid binary(32)
```

And the result is the error:

> "Failed to convert parameter value
>   from a Int64 to a Byte[]."

I have tried:

1. ... = Convert.ToByte(settingsPropertyValue.PropertyValue);
2. ... = Convert.ToInt64(settingsPropertyValue.PropertyValue);

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SqlDbType.Binary` is not correct (when you add the parameter) -- that's for extended binary data of arbitrary length.  You want to just represent it as a 64-bit integer, which is `SqlDbType.BigInt`.

By the way, why are you doing this in the first place?  SQL has a date-time type; you can just store it like that.

(You could go about it in the opposite, perverse way and instead convert the long to an eight-byte array and pass that, but there's no conceivable reason you would want to store it in that manner.)

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("sessionid", SqlDbType.BigInt, sizeof(Int64)).Value = settingsPropertyValue.PropertyValue; And got "value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte". Does that look right?

Comment: What datatype is it in SQL Server?

Comment: sessionid | binary(32) | null

Comment: Oh, woops. I need to convert the datatype in SQL to BigInt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ToBinary` doesn't do what you think it does.

The [`DateTime.ToBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) method returns  a `long` value, not a byte array.

What are you trying to do?

If you're trying to store the datetime, you should just use a DataTime column.

If you actually want a byte array, please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks. I do want ToBinary to give me the long value. I am creating a session ID using, essentially, long sessionId = DateTime.Now.ToBinary. Then, I am Storing it in the DB and retrieving it and converting it back to DateTime as needed. However, I think I am getting mixed up as to how to store it.